# Чтение данных из Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-database

Я должен сделать прогрмму, которая читает данные из БД в Firebase, но ничего не выводится на экран. Что надо изменить?

```
        private void init(){
        listView = findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        listData= new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USER_KEY);
    }
    private void getDataFromDB(){
        ValueEventListener vListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (listData.size() > 0)listData.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user!= null;
                    listData.add(user.name);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        mDataBase.addValueEventListener(vListener);
    }
```

Comment: какие данные вам нужно показать и где?

Comment: Данные из БД. Их нужно показать в в отдельной activity. Я пытаюсь сделать что-то похожее на раздел новостей.